# vba - insert formula range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a formula into the last used row of Column A, and have the formula auto-fill until the last used row of Column B.

The code works - but it is also overwriting the data in Columns B and C and inserting the formula into them.

Here is my code:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("Raw Data")
        Set rngA = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
            rngA.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("D9").Value
    End With
End With
```

Can anyone help me pinpoint which section of code is causing the issue and how to fix?

Comment: Read the line where you assign your range object carefully. You explicitly tell vba that you want to start your range at the last cell of column A, then your second section is set for the last cell of column B with 1 column offset.

Comment: I can't see that you are inserting a formula. Where should the formula go in B? From the last row in A to the last row in B?

Comment: The formula is actually a value in the instructions page that is being referenced (last line before 'End With'). The formula/value should be inserted after the last used row in ColA and auto-fill until the last used row in ColB - so both ColA and B should end on the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and see if that works for you:

```
Dim lrA as Long, lrB as Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
    lrA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lrB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(lrA+1,1),.Cells(lrB,1)).Formula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("D9").Formula
End With
```

You might want to change `A1` into whatever is the first cell with your formulas.